# Helping Rails Newbies identify version-specific information on web pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to help some people getting started programming on rails identify which version that advice found on web pages corresponds to, and am seeking advice and/or guides on how to do it so they don't have to rely on me and/or waste time trying outdated advice.

Narrative:  I am helping some people get up to speed on rails development, and their stock response to running into problems is searching google for advice.  They're using 2.3.5 and thinking of moving to 3.  The problem they're running into is that there's a lot of advice out there specific to older rails versions (2.2 for example being popular) that isn't identified.

I can usually figure out when the pages are old pretty easily, but they can't (yet.)  It seems like random web page authors don't identify which version they're using when they're using the current version, and not all pages are dated.

This seems to be a general problem that will get worse -- current unadorned advice is usually 2.3.5 and older unadorned advice is 2.2.x at this point, but people are moving / [will be moving to version 3 over the next while](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/rails-3-beta-is-out-a-retrospective/) and newbies will be stuck looking at a bunch of deprecated/incompatible 2.3.x advice without realizing which version it is.

Any advice / pointers / telltales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [API Dock](http://apidock.com/rails). It has an excellent, annotated, and more importantly, *versioned* documentation of the rails API.

Answer (score 0):

When I started with Rails 2.x last year, I got some books that were talking on Rails 1.x

There were things that changed from 1.x to 2.x, such as the way scaffolding works or that a framework like [streamlined](http://streamlinedframework.org/) stopped from existence. On the other hand, there were some concepts and points that stayed valid from Rails 1.x to 2.x  For example, most tutorials and documents start on talking about the model layer, how easy it is to use ActiveRecord and how you have REST for dealing with basic CRUD operations.

In general, I think with such an active community, it's actually one of the strong point of rails that you get so many shifts in innovation so fast. Actually, it is one of the strong points of the open-source community.

Comment: Right, I'm in agreement with you that this is one of the strong points of rails.  However, it isn't relevant to people attempting to learn rails, which is the primary point of this question.

Comment: One source to point would be irc: #ror, #railsbridge

There is also a webpage of railsbridge:  www.railsbridge.org